# in this code the message box is show that data has been successfully saved but in databse there no showing of data

Tags: c#, sql

in this code the message box is show that data has been successfully saved but in databse there no showing of data .

```
namespace Login_Form
{
    public partial class frmCreateCompany : Form
    {
        SqlConnection con = null;
        SqlDataAdapter adp;
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        SqlCommand cmd = null;
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        public frmCreateCompany()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


        }
        private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.\\SqlExpress; Integrated Security=True; AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\\Garment.mdf; User Instance=true;");
            con.Open();

            if (textBox2.Text == "")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please enter Company Name", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                textBox2.Focus();
                return;
            }
            if (textBox3.Text == "")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please enter Mailing  Name", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                textBox3.Focus();
                return;
            }
            if (textBox4.Text == "")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please enter License Number", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                textBox4.Focus();
                return;
            }
            if (textBox5.Text == "")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please enter Post Offcie Number", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                textBox5.Focus();
                return;
            }
            if (textBox6.Text == "")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please enter Location", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                textBox6.Focus();
                return;
            }
            if (textBox7.Text == "")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please enter State", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                textBox7.Focus();
                return;
            }
            if (textBox8.Text == "")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please enter Country", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                textBox8.Focus();
                return;
            }
            if (textBox9.Text == "")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please enter Telephone Number", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                textBox9.Focus();
                return;
            }
            if (textBox10.Text == "")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please enter Fax No.", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                textBox10.Focus();
                return;
            }
            if (textBox11.Text == "")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please enter Email id", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                textBox11.Focus();
                return;
            }
            if (textBox12.Text == "")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please enter Website Name", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                textBox12.Focus();
                return;
            }
            if (textBox13.Text == "")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please enter Currency Name", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                textBox13.Focus();
                return;
            }
            if (AccountingStart.Text == "")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please Select Start date ", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                AccountingStart.Focus();
                return;
            }
            if (AccountingFrom.Text == "")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please Select End date ", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                AccountingFrom.Focus();
                return;
            }

            try
            {

                //con = new SqlConnection(cs);
                //con.Open();
                string cb = "INSERT INTO COMPANY_MASTER(C_Name,M_Name,L_No,Tax_No,PO_No,Location,State,Country,Telephone,Fax_No,Email_Id,Website,Currency_Name,Company_logo,APT,APF) VALUES(@d1,@d2,@d3,@d4,@d5,@d6,@d7,@d8,@d9,@d10,@d11,@d12,@d13,@d14,@d15,@d16)";
                cmd = new SqlCommand(cb);
                cmd.Connection = con;
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@d1", System.Data.SqlDbType.NChar, 10, "C_Name"));
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@d2", System.Data.SqlDbType.NChar, 10, "M_Name"));
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@d3", System.Data.SqlDbType.NChar, 10, "L_No"));
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@d4", System.Data.SqlDbType.NChar, 10, "Tax_No"));
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@d5", System.Data.SqlDbType.NChar, 10, "PO_No"));
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@d6", System.Data.SqlDbType.NChar, 10, "Location"));
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@d7", System.Data.SqlDbType.NChar, 10, "State"));
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@d8", System.Data.SqlDbType.NChar, 10, "Country"));
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@d9", System.Data.SqlDbType.NChar, 10, "Telephone"));
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@d10", System.Data.SqlDbType.NChar, 10, "Fax_No"));
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@d11", System.Data.SqlDbType.NChar, 10, "email_Id"));
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@d12", System.Data.SqlDbType.NChar, 10, "Website"));
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@d13", System.Data.SqlDbType.NChar, 10, "Currency_Name"));
                MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
                Bitmap bmpImage = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Image);
                bmpImage.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);

                byte[] data = ms.GetBuffer();
                SqlParameter p = new SqlParameter("@d14", SqlDbType.Image);
                p.Value = data;
                cmd.Parameters.Add(p);
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@d15", System.Data.SqlDbType.Date, 30, "APT"));
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@d16", System.Data.SqlDbType.Date, 30, "APF"));


                cmd.Parameters["@d1"].Value = textBox2.Text.Trim();
                cmd.Parameters["@d2"].Value = textBox3.Text.Trim();
                cmd.Parameters["@d3"].Value = textBox4.Text.Trim();
                cmd.Parameters["@d4"].Value = textBox5.Text.Trim();
                cmd.Parameters["@d5"].Value = textBox6.Text.Trim();
                cmd.Parameters["@d6"].Value = textBox7.Text.Trim();
                cmd.Parameters["@d7"].Value = textBox8.Text.Trim();
                cmd.Parameters["@d8"].Value = textBox9.Text.Trim();
                cmd.Parameters["@d9"].Value = textBox10.Text.Trim();
                cmd.Parameters["@d10"].Value = textBox11.Text.Trim();
                cmd.Parameters["@d11"].Value = textBox12.Text.Trim();
                cmd.Parameters["@d12"].Value = textBox13.Text.Trim();
                cmd.Parameters["@d13"].Value = textBox14.Text.Trim();
                cmd.Parameters["@d14"].Value = p.Value;

                cmd.Parameters["@d15"].Value = AccountingStart.Text.Trim();
                cmd.Parameters["@d16"].Value = AccountingFrom.Text.Trim();

                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                //cmd.ExecuteReader();

                con.Close();
                MessageBox.Show("Successfully saved ", "Company", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }




        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var _with1 = openFileDialog1;

            _with1.Filter = ("Images |*.png; *.bmp; *.jpg;*.jpeg; *.gif; *.ico");
            _with1.FilterIndex = 4;

            //Reset the file name
            openFileDialog1.FileName = "";

            if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                pictureBox1.Image=Image.FromFile(openFileDialog1.FileName);

            }
        }
       }
    }
```

Comment: You get any exception or error message?

Comment: No there is no error message just show the message box of that data has been successfully saved but in table there is no row affected

Comment: try enclosing `State` in bracket `[State]`. May be this will be helpful.

Comment: @HassanNisar `STATE` might be a [reserved keyword](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189822.aspx) in future releases of SQL Server. Not now.

Comment: @user3510293 What is your `cmd` looks like when you debug your code before you execute it?

Comment: @SonerGönül right it is reserved keyword for future releases of SQL Server. But still enclosing column names in brackets is good practice.

Comment: give me ur email Id i will send you this form please resolve the probs

Comment: How are you checking if the update is successful or not- Another command in the same application?

Comment: `ExecuteNonQuery()` returns `int`. For UPDATE, INSERT, and DELETE statements, the return value is the number of rows affected by the command. Check if return value is greater than 0 then your query is successful.

Comment: tell me what will be change itno code Hassan Nisar

Comment: @user3510293 Follow the changes as mentioned in Answer below.

Answer (score 0):

To get number of rows affected you have to perform following check:

```
int iResult = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();

if(iResult > 0)
   MessageBox.Show("Successfully saved ", "Company", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
else
   MessageBox.Show("Record not saved ", "Company", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
```

**UPDATE**:

Replace this line in the code:

```
SqlParameter p = new SqlParameter("@d14", SqlDbType.Image);
```

with

```
SqlParameter p = new SqlParameter("@d14", SqlDbType.Image, data.Length, "Company_logo");
```

Answer (score 0):

I have changed your database code. Looks like you are setting a sql date type but assigning the value as a string. Try the below code, I have not tested it but it should work.

```
        DateTime? dtStart = null, dtFrom = null;

        try
        {
            dtStart = DateTime.Parse(AccountingStart.Text.Trim());
        }
        catch { }

        if (!dtStart.HasValue)
        { 
            // error check here.
        }

        try
        {
            dtFrom = DateTime.Parse(AccountingFrom.Text.Trim());
        }
        catch { }

        if (!dtFrom.HasValue)
        { 
            // error check here.
        }

        using (SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.\\SqlExpress; Integrated Security=True; AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\\Garment.mdf; User Instance=true;"))
        {
            sqlConn.Open();
            SqlTransaction sqlTransaction = null;

            string cb = "INSERT INTO COMPANY_MASTER(C_Name,M_Name,L_No,Tax_No,PO_No,Location,State,Country,Telephone,Fax_No,Email_Id,Website,Currency_Name,Company_logo,APT,APF) VALUES(@d1,@d2,@d3,@d4,@d5,@d6,@d7,@d8,@d9,@d10,@d11,@d12,@d13,@d14,@d15,@d16)";

            try
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = sqlConn.CreateCommand();
                cmd.CommandText = cb;
                sqlTransaction = sqlConn.BeginTransaction();
                cmd.Transaction = sqlTransaction;
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@1", SqlDbType.NChar, 10, ParameterDirection.Input, false, 0, 0, "C_Name", DataRowVersion.Current, textBox2.Text.Trim()));
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@2", SqlDbType.NChar, 10, ParameterDirection.Input, false, 0, 0, "M_Name", DataRowVersion.Current, textBox3.Text.Trim()));
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@3", SqlDbType.NChar, 10, ParameterDirection.Input, false, 0, 0, "L_No", DataRowVersion.Current, textBox4.Text.Trim()));
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@4", SqlDbType.NChar, 10, ParameterDirection.Input, false, 0, 0, "Tax_No", DataRowVersion.Current, textBox5.Text.Trim()));
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@5", SqlDbType.NChar, 10, ParameterDirection.Input, false, 0, 0, "PO_No", DataRowVersion.Current, textBox6.Text.Trim()));
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@6", SqlDbType.NChar, 10, ParameterDirection.Input, false, 0, 0, "Location", DataRowVersion.Current, textBox7.Text.Trim()));
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@7", SqlDbType.NChar, 10, ParameterDirection.Input, false, 0, 0, "State", DataRowVersion.Current, textBox8.Text.Trim()));
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@8", SqlDbType.NChar, 10, ParameterDirection.Input, false, 0, 0, "Country", DataRowVersion.Current, textBox9.Text.Trim()));
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@9", SqlDbType.NChar, 10, ParameterDirection.Input, false, 0, 0, "Telephone", DataRowVersion.Current, textBox10.Text.Trim()));
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@10", SqlDbType.NChar, 10, ParameterDirection.Input, false, 0, 0, "Fax_No", DataRowVersion.Current, textBox11.Text.Trim()));
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@11", SqlDbType.NChar, 10, ParameterDirection.Input, false, 0, 0, "email_Id", DataRowVersion.Current, textBox12.Text.Trim()));
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@12", SqlDbType.NChar, 10, ParameterDirection.Input, false, 0, 0, "Website", DataRowVersion.Current, textBox13.Text.Trim()));
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@13", SqlDbType.NChar, 10, ParameterDirection.Input, false, 0, 0, "Currency_Name", DataRowVersion.Current, textBox14.Text.Trim()));

                using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    using (Bitmap bmpImage = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Image))
                    {
                        bmpImage.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                        byte[] data = ms.GetBuffer();

                        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@14", SqlDbType.Image, 10, ParameterDirection.Input, false, 0, 0, "Currency_Name", DataRowVersion.Current, data));
                    }
                }

                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@15", SqlDbType.DateTime, 8, ParameterDirection.Input, false, 0, 0, "APT", DataRowVersion.Current, dtStart));
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@16", SqlDbType.DateTime, 8, ParameterDirection.Input, false, 0, 0, "APF", DataRowVersion.Current, dtFrom));

                cmd.ExecuteScalar();
                sqlTransaction.Commit();

                MessageBox.Show("Successfully saved ", "Company", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                try
                {
                    sqlTransaction.Rollback();
                }
                catch { }

                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }
```